# FlowCoverAPi in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have implemented Flow-cover Api in my application. Just need to know weather it will be accepted by apple.

If Yes then there is something called as BSD-style Liscense so just need to know what exactly is BSD-style Liscense and how do i get that Liscense.

Please follow the link below as i am using this Api
http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m

Thanks in advance

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try reading the [license](http://www.chaosinmotion.com/wiki/index.php?title=License):

> Redistribution and use in source and
>   binary forms, with or without
>   modification, are permitted

FlowCover is released under that license, you do not need to apply for it.

Answer (score 0):

Please Read this for BSD license

[BSD License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php)

[License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses)